# Select all values in column that don't contain the character in another

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have two columns:

```
Table: MyTable

myString  myChar
--------------------
cat         c       
dog         m        
chicken     p
bat         a
```

I'm looking for a query that would select only those items in which myString contains the char in myChar, i.e. cat and bat.

Is there a way to do something like the following:

SELECT * from MyTable where myString LIKE '%$myChar%';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE INSTR(myString, myChar) <> 0
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE INSTR(myString, myChar)
```

Avoid using `SELECT *` in production and instead select the columns you will actually use.